# httpd-mmn = 20051115 required by "yum install php"

Tags: php, apache, centos, yum, apache2.4

I installed httpd (apache 2.4.6) from source and now I want to install PHP. But `yum install php` spits out the error:

```
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
       Installed: httpd-2.4.6-1.x86_64 (installed)
           httpd-mmn = 20120211
       Available: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
           httpd-mmn = 20051115
```

I've also tried with `webtatic`, `ius` and `remi`. All with the same error. I built apache using rpm-build.

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/yum.conf
```

Remove httpd* and php* from this line:

```
exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* perl* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

Save and close yum.conf

Try again:

```
$ sudo yum install php
```

Answer (score 2):

The php package you are trying to install is actually mod_php, which is compiled against a specific Apache HTTP Server ABI (httpd-mmn).  Stock php, IUS, Webtatic, and Remirepo all build against stock httpd.  <s>Some Remi packages build against stock, but other build against versions of httpd he ships.</s>  Compiling your own httpd from source will typically mean having to compile your own mod_php as well.

If you just need php, not mod_php specifically, you can use php-fpm instead, and that will avoid this problem entirely.  IUS currently ships php55u-fpm, php56u-fpm, and php70u-fpm packages if you need a more recent version than the stock 5.3.

Comment: Remi repository is now dedicated to PHP, no httpd, only the PHP stack build against the base httpd package.

Comment: Weren't there some SCL PHP packages that required httpd24?  Or did you remove those?

Comment: Only RHSCL php packages use httpd in RHSCL.  Not in my repo.

Answer (score 0):

I you start to build from sources (Apache), you have to build nearly "everything" from sources.

Of course you can also switch to php-fpm.