# Error occurred when installing mod_wsgi on apache2.4

Tags: python, centos6

I'm using mod_wsgi for my python web. I'm using centos6. When I try

```
yum install mod_wsgi
```

I found that it gives me an error:

```
Error: Package: mod_wsgi-3.2-7.el6.x86_64 (base) Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've been on the same problem too! It's probably because you are using Cpanel. if you create it outside of the cPanel system, mod_wsgi.so will vanish each time you run easy_apache to upgrade your apache and php.

So the key is to install this mod_wsgi for cPanel module.To build mod_wsgi through easy_apache. Download custom_opt_mod-mod_wsgi.tar.gz from [HERE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/issues/214) at google code and run:

```
tar -C /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods -xzf custom_opt_mod-mod_wsgi.tar.gz
```

That unpacks the module into the right location so that easy_apache will find it and present it as a build option. Run easy_apache as usual (either via script or through WHM) and select the mod_wsgi option. When complete, you’ll find mod_wsgi.so along with all your other modules in /usr/local/apache/modules. The best part is, this will now become part of the default easy_apache build process, so your sites won’t break when you rebuild apache+php in the future.

Original answer at [building-mod_wsgi-easyapache-for-whmcpanel](http://blog.birdhouse.org/2011/08/11/building-mod_wsgi-easyapache-for-whmcpanel/)

Comment: No problems, buddy

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872457/httpd-mmn-20051115-required-by-yum-install-php

mod_wsgi is built against a specific Apache (HTTPD) version. you will need to make sure HTTPD is installed and the same version as the mod_wsgi you are trying to install

Run the following command "sudo rpm -q httpd" to see if apache(HTTPD) is installed and what version.

If you are using cPanel to manage your server you will not be able to install Apache Modules using YUM as the modules are compiled for a specific version of Apache and will not work with a different version. Since cPanel uses EasyApache you will need use cPanel to add modules to apache.

Original answer at [getting error while hosting Python based web applications](https://fr.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/getting-error-while-hosting-Python-based-web-applications/td-p/38598).

Comment: Yeah I'm using WHM Cpanel, and I also read this original answer, but it wasn't clear enough, thanks anyway